# Is there any gcc compiler warning which could have caught this memory bug?

Tags: c, gcc, memory-management, gcc-warning

I haven't programmed C for quite some time and my pointer-fu had degraded. I made a very elementary mistake and it took me well over an hour this morning to find what I'd done. The bug is minimally reproduced here: https://godbolt.org/z/3MdzarP67 (I am aware the program is absurd memory-management wise, just showing what happens).

The first call to `realloc()` breaks because of course, the pointer it's given points to stack memory, `valgrind` made this quite obvious.

I have a rule with myself where any time I track down a bug, if there is a warning that could have caught it I enable it on my projects. Often times this is not the case, since many bugs come from logic errors the compiler can't be expected to check.

However here I am a bit surprised. We `malloc()` and then immediately reassign that pointer which leaves the allocated memory inaccessible. It's obvious the returned pointer does not live outside the scope of that `if` block, and is never `free()`'d. Maybe it's too much to expect the compiler to analyze the calls and realize we're attempting to `realloc()` stack memory but I am surprised that I can't find anything to yell at me about the leaking of the `malloc()` returned pointer. Even `clang`'s static analyzer `scan-build` doesn't pick up on it, I've tried various relevant options.

The best I could find was `-fsanitize=address` which at least prints out some cluing information during the crash instead of:

```
mremap_chunk(): invalid pointer
```

on Godbolt, or

```
realloc(): invalid old size
Aborted (core dumped)
```

on my machine, both of which are somewhat cryptic (although yes they do show plainly that there is *some* memory issue occurring). Still, this compiles without issues.

Since Godbolt links don't live forever here is the critical section of the code:

```
void add_foo_to_bar(struct Bar** b, Foo* f) {
    if ((*b)->foos == NULL) {
        (*b)->foos = (Foo*)malloc(sizeof(Foo));
        // uncomment for correction
        //(*b)->foos[(*b)->n_foos] = *f;      
        // obvious bug here, we leak memory by losing the returned pointer from malloc
        // and assign the pointer to a stack address (&f1)
        // comment below line for correction
        (*b)->foos = f; // completely wrong
        (*b)->n_foos++;
    } else {
        (*b)->foos = (Foo*)realloc((*b)->foos, ((*b)->n_foos + 1) * sizeof(Foo));
        (*b)->foos[(*b)->n_foos] = *f;
        (*b)->n_foos++;
    }
}
```

the error occurs because f is a pointer to stack memory (intentional) but we obviously can't assign something that was supposed to have been `malloc()`'d to that.

Comment: I doubt a compiler could catch that error. After all, *anything* could have been done to `(*b)->foos` between the call with that being `NULL` and with it not being `NULL`. I guess it would need a *runtime* checker (like Valgrind).

Comment: Not sure that `gcc` can pick this up. But [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) certainly will. It may not tell you explicitly but will certainly tell you that the `malloc` memory has been leaked which would be a strong clue.

Comment: @kaylum Yup, valgrind is exactly how I found this. Complained that the pointer to realloc() was stack memory. Still took me a bit to figure out how on earth it got to be that way, but at least pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Although clang (or its static analyzer) will likely warn about possibly losing the 'old' pointer value in your call to `realloc`: code like `a = realloc(a,n)` is bad practice because, if the call fails, you've lost the original pointer forever.

Comment: Step 1 would be to rewrite this code so that it only works on a local pointer `Bar* bar;`. Then assign everything to that pointer and in the end `*b = bar;`. Gets rid of the obscure syntax but will yield the same machine code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `-fanalyzer` if your compiler is recent enough. When running it I get:

```
../main.c:30:28: warning: ‘realloc’ of ‘&f1’ which points to memory not on the heap [CWE-590] [-Wanalyzer-free-of-non-heap]
   30 |         (*b)->foos = (Foo*)realloc((*b)->foos, ((*b)->n_foos + 1) * sizeof(Foo));
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ‘main’: events 1-2
    |
    |   37 | int main() {
    |      |     ^~~~
    |      |     |
    |      |     (1) entry to ‘main’
    |......
    |   45 |     add_foo_to_bar(&b, &f1);
    |      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    |      |     |
    |      |     (2) calling ‘add_foo_to_bar’ from ‘main’
    |
    +--> ‘add_foo_to_bar’: events 3-5
           |
           |   19 | void add_foo_to_bar(struct Bar** b, Foo* f) {
           |      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           |      |      |
           |      |      (3) entry to ‘add_foo_to_bar’
           |   20 |     if ((*b)->foos == NULL) {
           |      |        ~
           |      |        |
           |      |        (4) following ‘true’ branch...
           |   21 |         (*b)->foos = (Foo*)malloc(sizeof(Foo));
           |      |         ~~~~
           |      |          |
           |      |          (5) ...to here
           |
    <------+
    |
  ‘main’: events 6-7
    |
    |   45 |     add_foo_to_bar(&b, &f1);
    |      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    |      |     |
    |      |     (6) returning to ‘main’ from ‘add_foo_to_bar’
    |   46 |     add_foo_to_bar(&b, &f2);
    |      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    |      |     |
    |      |     (7) calling ‘add_foo_to_bar’ from ‘main’
    |
    +--> ‘add_foo_to_bar’: events 8-11
           |
           |   19 | void add_foo_to_bar(struct Bar** b, Foo* f) {
           |      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           |      |      |
           |      |      (8) entry to ‘add_foo_to_bar’
           |   20 |     if ((*b)->foos == NULL) {
           |      |        ~
           |      |        |
           |      |        (9) following ‘false’ branch...
           |......
           |   30 |         (*b)->foos = (Foo*)realloc((*b)->foos, ((*b)->n_foos + 1) * sizeof(Foo));
           |      |                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
           |      |                            |                     |
           |      |                            |                     (10) ...to here
           |      |                            (11) call to ‘realloc’ here
           |
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither gcc 7.5 nor clang 6.0 seem to support this but I do see what it would have printed on Godbolt and it correctly warns about the leaked memory, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, but, runtime testing can save you.

If you can spare the execution overhead, I have seen many applications add an extra layer to memory allocation to track the allocations made and find leaks/errors.
Usually they replace malloc() and free() with a macros that include **FILE** and **LINE**

One example can be seen here (check the Heap.c and Heap.h files)
https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.c/tree/master/src

Googling "memory heap debugger" will probably turn up other examples. Or you could roll your own.